# VBA Excel to highlight range on another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, range, worksheet

Long time lurker here, I've finally been stumped trying to code some VBA to highlight from columns B to S on another worksheet, for all rows that have a value in column S greater than H10 on the other worksheet. This code works fine:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To Rows.Count
If Worksheets("Initial Data").Cells(i, 19).Value > Worksheets("Inputs").Range("H10").Value Then
Worksheets("Initial Data").Cells(i, 19).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End If
Next i
Worksheets("Initial Data").Activate
```

This will highlight each cell in column S that is required. What I want to do is highlight cells from B to S, something like this:

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To Rows.Count
If Worksheets("Initial Data").Cells(i, 19).Value > Worksheets("Inputs").Range("H10").Value Then
Worksheets("Initial Data").Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 19)).Interior.ColorIndex = 2
End If
Next i
Worksheets("Initial Data").Activate
```

...but it doesnt work, I get a runtime error. This is so frustrating as I've done the bulk of the hard stuff!

Oh and before anyone suggests conditional formatting, the data the sub reads from is freshly pasted each time, so thats a no no. thanks for any input!

Comment: The data is .Paste < into the sheet or manually pasted? Even if its pasted you can still do conditional formatting. You only need make sure the Values are pasted nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove dot before `.Cells(i, 2)` vba dont know which cells you mean

change `Worksheets("Initial Data").Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 19)).Interior.ColorIndex = 2` 
to
`Worksheets("Initial Data").Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 19)).Interior.ColorIndex = 2`

or use `With` -> [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx):

```
With Worksheets("Initial Data")
    .Range(.Cells(i, 2), .Cells(i, 19)).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End With
```

Comment: The first one didn't work but the With statement worked great, thanks! I'd tried the with statement before but without the .

Comment: you can check also this `Worksheets("Initial Data").Range(Worksheets("Initial Data").Cells(i, 2), Worksheets("Initial Data").Cells(i, 19)).Interior.ColorIndex = 2`

Comment: @Dawid  Without the `With ...`  your (first) suggestion will work if and only if `Initial Data` is the Active Sheet